# 'Clicking' problem with dodge sprinter 2004 - won't crank

Tags: starting, noise, dodge, van, sprinter

I recently purchased my 2004 Dodge Sprinter 3500 used at 149,000 miles. I'm converting it into a camper van.

Every other time I open the door to the sprinter, this clicking sound starts. It goes for 20 seconds, then stops. The sound starts up again as soon as I turn the key. It doesn't crank at all.

Because of this clicking I can't start my sprinter. any ideas on what's causing this?

Here's a video that shows the sound: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GGEtvF98YPc&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Is your battery in good condition and fully charged is the first check

Comment: It seems like the noise could be the fuel pump relay. You say it "doesn't crank at all". Do you mean it doesn't want to start (engine rotates on key, but doesn't have any life) or the engine itself will not turn over? In the video you never turn the key to show us what's going on when you try to start it.

Comment: yes! My battery is good. AAA said it had good health.

Comment: The key rotates, and the engine doesn't want to start.